# Partitioning $[0,C]^2$ with product sets

Tags: measure-theory, infinite-combinatorics, packing-and-covering

Let $S= \{A^2:A\subset \Bbb{R}, \mu(A)\le 1\}, T = \{(A\times B)\cup (B\times A):A\subset B \subset \Bbb{R}, \mu(A)\le 1/2\}$, where $\times$ denotes the cartesian product and $\mu$ is the standard Lebesgue measure on the reals. Also, for a set $E \subset \Bbb{R}^2$, we define $P(E)$ to be the set of real numbers $x$ such that $(x,y) \in E$ and/or $(y,x)\in E$ for some $y\in \Bbb{R}$. (you may wish to think of $P$ as being a projection)

I am wondering about the function $f(C)$, which returns the smallest integer $k$ such that there exists a cover $\mathcal{C}\subset S\cup T$, so that
$$[0,C]^2 = \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{C}} U$$
$$ \mathcal{C} = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^k \mathcal{C}_i, \quad U,V \in \mathcal{C}_i \implies P(U)\cap P(V) = \emptyset .$$
(i.e. $\mathcal{C}$ covers $[0,C]^2$ and can be partitioned into $k$ collections of subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$ whose projections are pairwise disjoint)

Has this kind of problem been studied before, for perhaps some different base $S\cup T$? If so, are there any useful general techniques, and would this particular case be considered a hard problem?

**Context:**

I'm asking because I realize that if $f(k-x)\le k$ for $k\in \Bbb{Z},x \in [1/2,1]$, then the Ramsey number for paths of length $n$ and $k$ colors, $R_k(P_n)$, is at least $(k-x)n$ asymptotically. (for $k>3$, we currently only know $(k-1)n +o(n)\le R_k(P_n)\le (k-1/2)n +o(n)$) It is not hard to reprove the current best lower bound with this observation, but for $x<1$ I was unable to find covers. I was also able to prove that one cannot do better than taking $x$ to be $1$ if we only use covers in $T$, but could not extend this.

Comment: Do you really pit  no restrictions on $B$?

Comment: While right now it is possible that allowing non-measureable $B$ may not work with my intended application for Ramsey paths, nevertheless I am interested in the general problem and perhaps can adjust my methods to accommodate a covering which involves pathological sets once I am aware of a specific case. I am not currently an expert in exploiting the axiom of choice, and would love to learn some tricks. The main restriction imposed is that for each $\mathcal{C}_i$, the chosen $B$ partition $[0,C]$. (along with the chosen $A$ corresponding to elements of $S$)

Comment: You really want $\bigcap_{U\in C_i}U=\emptyset$, and not $U\cap V=\emptyset$ for all distinct $U,V\in C_i$?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, fixed.

Comment: Why on earth should the chosen $B$ (for one $\mathcal C_i$) partition $[0,C]$? I see no restriction which claims that...

Comment: Apologies, I believe I have properly edited the question now. I now introduced a notion of projection, and am requiring the projection of sets be disjoint. Somehow I forgot about this when I visualized the problem. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Let $R_k(\mathcal{H}_n)$ be the smallest integer $N$ such that in any $k$-coloring of $K_N$ there is a monochromatic copy of some $H\in \mathcal{H}_n$, where $\mathcal{H}_n$ is the family of connected graphs on $n$ vertices. 

Can you use this method to say anything about $R_k(\mathcal{H}_n)$?  Here the covers would have to come only from $S$ I think.

It is known that $R_k(\mathcal{H}_n)=(k-1)n+\Theta(1)$ whenever an affine plane of order $k-1$ exists.  Part of the reason I ask is that the asymptotic value of $R_7(\mathcal{H}_n)$ is unknown, but it is at most $35n/6+O(1)$.

Comment: Also, you might consider adding the connection to the path Ramsey problem in the title somehow.  I think this would help generate more attention.